# How to store a environment variable for use by another script without source

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to create two scripts. One called backup, the other called cancel_backup. When backup is ran, it checks if a directory is available, if so it begins the backup. If not, it tries again every 30 seconds until the directory is found.

If cancel_backup is ran, the backup script should terminate.

Here's my code so far:

```
#/bin/bash!

backup_location='/media/tom/EXTERNAL/Backups/Areca'  

while [ ! -d $backup_location ]
do
  if [ ! $CANCEL_BACKUP ]
  then
    notify-send --icon=/home/tom/icons/dialog-warning.png "Backup Cancelled." "Backup has been cancelled by the user."
    exit 0
  else
    notify-send --icon=/home/tom/icons/dialog-error.png "Backup Directory Inaccessible" "External backup directory is inaccessible. Retrying in 30 seconds."
    sleep 30
  fi
done

notify-send --icon=/home/tom/icons/dialog-info.png "Beginning Backup" "External backup directory located, beginning backup."
```

I've attempted to use export, however the variable is still not accessible to any other scripts unless they I use source within the above script.

I need to be able to run the scripts independently, but still update $CANCEL_BACKUP from a different script.

Comment: Child processes cannot change variables of their parents, that's why you need to `source`. Maybe decide based on exit codes of your scripts?

Comment: Environment variables are only inherited by children, there's no way to propagate variables the other way. Use a file as a flag instead of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a file as the flag rather than a variable.

```
cancel_file=/tmp/cancel_backup

if [ ! -f $cancel_file ]
```

The `cancel_backup` script can then do `touch /tmp/cancel_backup`. And you remove the file when you want to enable backups again.

`/tmp` might not be the best place for the file, since some other user could create the file there. Better would be a directory used specifically for the application, which only the application user has access to. The above was just a simple example.

Comment: I might argue about the location of the file in `/tmp`, but the rest is what I'd suggest doing. Given `backup_location='/media/tom/EXTERNAL/Backups/Areca' ` in the main script, I'd suggest `cancel_file='/media/tom/EXTERNAL/Backups/cancel_backup` as a more appropriate location.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Umm..., just curious, but what would you suggest? LSB would suggest `/tmp` for general temporary files, and it would avoid the system `/run` directory (or `/var/run` or `/lib/run` on some distros), but perhaps `/usr/local/run` setgid to a group for those that have privilege to run backup? (I'm thinking like a pid-file)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I added a suggestion.  The fixed name in `/tmp` is a security liability on a multi-user system (a rarity, but it is worth remembering them).  Placing the fixed name near where the operations are occurring seems appropriate to me.  Also, it isn't a temporary file; it is a control file.  If it must go under `/tmp`, I'd think about how to make it safer — and less likely to interfere with other people also trying to run their own backups.  Options include a file in a sub-directory under `/tmp` with appropriate permissions, but it can't be a fixed name, which complicates things.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suspect `/media/tom` is a removable device (that's why the directory might or might not be avaiable), so it's probably not the right place for the flag. Or maybe it is -- if the device isn't mounted, the cancel file is not relevant.

Comment: I gotcha and concur. The run-control is what I was thinking. If only a single user runs the file, then the current directory is fine, but if it is run from a bin directory (either the users personal collection where more than one needs to be able to run it or `/usr/local/bin`,) then a local `run/ex_backup` dir could be created or a pid-file like file in a safer location.

Comment: That `/media/tom` might be removable is a legitimate concern; it would suggest that the location I mentioned isn't the best alternative.  @DavidC.Rankin: Like many things, it's a design decision, and with due caution about the use of `/tmp` or `/usr/tmp` (or even `$TMPDIR`), most choices can be acceptable.  The key is not to place it in `/tmp` willy-nilly or without consideration — and the other key is to use a file rather than trying to tinker with environment variables.  This discussion down in the weeds shouldn't obscure the high-level message.